# Proper subsumes_term/2 in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, sicstus-prolog

Lets assume SICStus Prolog is the benchmark for the
implementation of certain predicates, even ISO core standard
predicates. Especially in connection with attributed variables.

I then find these examples [here](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus/mpg_002dref_002dsubsumes_005fterm.html). It's from SICStus 4 and not only SICStus 3:

```
?- when(nonvar(X), X=a), subsumes_term(X, b), X = a.
X = a ? 
yes

?- when(nonvar(X), X=a), subsumes_term(X, b), X = b.
no
```

When doing the same in SWI-Prolog I get different results:

```
?- when(nonvar(X), X=a), subsumes_term(X, b), X = a.
false.

?- when(nonvar(X), X=a), subsumes_term(X, b), X = b.
false.
```

How would one implement a workaround in SWI-Prolog? ROKs [METUTL.PL](http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/publib/metutl.html) probably doesn't help, since it uses normal unification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion (not actually tested in SWI-prolog):

```
subsumes_term_sicstus(X, Y):-
    copy_term(X-Y, XC-YC, _),
    subsumes_term(XC, YC).
```

The idea is simply to copy the two structures then use the original predicate on the copies, which do not have attributes or frozen goals attached.

According to the documentation, it appears that `copy_term/2` copies the attributes of attributed variables in SWI-prolog (but not in SICStus), so I am using `copy_term/3` instead here. I see that there is also a `copy_term_nat/2`, which might be used instead.

Comment: Yes, on SWI-Prolog discourse they were showing a solution with copy_term_nat/2. All this copying is of course not extremely efficient, but don't see much another solution for SWI-Prolog.